# A program to extract passwords from my Firefox profile

Tags: windows, firefox, password-manager

**UPDATE:** The question assumes there's no master password set in FF that protects the password DB.

As far as I'm aware, Firefox profiles store your website passwords in cleartext (or at least, not in hashed/salted form).

As such, I'm looking for a program that would let me extract the list of passwords from Firefox.

Requirements:

- Free or extremely cheap (under $1)
- Extracts from any version of Firefox on Windows that is less than 2 years old.
- Won't be broken just because FF bumped the version by 1 (assuming the new version doesn't change the password storage mechanism)
- Extra credit: ability to insert the extracted password file into a FF profile, replacing or augmenting current set of passwords.
- OK if the program is in the form of some Perl/Python published script; or standalone, or Mozilla plug-in - assuming the rule about FF version compatibility 2 years back stands.
- OS Compatibility: MUST work on Windows. But extra points if it works on other OSs, especially Android FF and Linux.

Comment: Extract format is irrelevant as long as it's cleartext and parseable by a script. XML, CSV, whatever

Answer (score 6):

Firefox profiles store website passwords in an easily decryptable format ([Base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), so it's more about encoding than encrypting) only if no [master password](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-master-password-protect-stored-logins) was set (if a master password is set then [3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) is used by default).

[FireMasterCracker](http://securityxploded.com/firefox-master-password-cracker.php) can recover the master password successfully from any Firefox browser, starting with version 1.0 or more. (dictionary-based attack, so it depends on the master password's strength)

[image]

---

If there is no master password, or you know the master password, you can use [FirePasswordViewer](http://securityxploded.com/firepasswordviewer.php)

- Free but not portable. Beware to decline the adware during installation.
- Extracts from any version of Firefox on Windows that is less than 2 years old.
- Won't be broken just because FF bumped the version by 1 (assuming the new version doesn't change the password storage mechanism)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The question assumes no master password was set.

Comment: OK I added a tool when there is no master password, or you know the master password.

Comment: And that, kids, is why you should never, ever use FF's native password manager. Yikes.

Comment: @user456584 how about other browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try NirSoft's [PasswordFox](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html).  I haven't use it specifically, but I've used a number of NirSoft's tools and found them to be, generally, of quite high quality.

[image: PasswordFox]
<sub>(source: [nirsoft.net](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.gif))</sub>